# How to get an Image from facebook and use ImageResizer MVC4 & C#

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, imageresizer

So I got this Image from facebook that I want to resize and if possible make it JPG.

Problem:
I dont have the right URL for the Image (I think) At the moment I'm using the:

```
graph.facebook.com/" + json["id"] + "/picture"
```

This will give me the link for the Image but not the .jpg session?`

So when I try to use ImageResize on this Image URL it doesn't recognize the url. Wich I understand..
So any idea on how I can get the ImageURL?
Thank you.

Comment: [WebImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) should allow you to retrieve it from the URL you have AND save it as a jpg.

Comment: @James - the problem isn't downloading the picture - it's that the HTTP response is just another URI. WebImage isn't helpful in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what I did was:

```
   public static string GetPictureUrl(string faceBookId)
        {

            WebResponse response = null;
            string pictureUrl = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?width=320&height=320", faceBookId));
                response = request.GetResponse();
                pictureUrl = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //? handle
            }
            finally
            {
                if (response != null) response.Close();
            }
            return pictureUrl;
        }
```

This lets me retrieve the URL of the image :)!

Comment: Looks good. Once you have an accurate URI, you can use RemoteReader to process it any way you want.